# How to add fade effect while changing CSS with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

I am faking fixed position for a footer on a mobile site for mobile browsers that don't support fixed-position. (iOS before iOS 5, Andriod before 2.2, etc.)

Here is the JQuery code I'm using, which works well and does what I want:

```
function changeFooterPosition() {   
  $('.not-fixed').css('top', window.innerHeight + window.scrollY - 56 + "px");
}

$(document).bind('scroll', function() {
  changeFooterPosition();
});
```

So that works.

My question is, I want to add a slight delay to it and have the footer fade into view rather than just snap quickly after every little scroll. I've looked around and found the following methods I could use, but I"m not sure if they are the correct ones or where to add them to the js above.

```
.delay(1000).fadeTo('slow', 1)
```

I know this functionality exists in JQuery Mobile, but I don't want to use the entirety of JQuery Mobile for just this one little thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both delay and fadeTo exist in "normal" jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try the animate function http://api.jquery.com/animate/

This won't fade but should move smoothly instead.

```
function changeFooterPosition() {   
  $('.not-fixed').animate({'top': window.innerHeight + window.scrollY - 56 + "px"}, 2000);
}

$(document).bind('scroll', changeFooterPosition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$(document).bind('scroll', function() {
  changeFooterPosition();
});
```

To

```
$(document).bind('scroll', changeFooterPosition);
```

Change

```
$('.not-fixed').css('top', window.innerHeight + window.scrollY - 56 + "px");
```

to

```
var WantedSpeed = 2000;
$('.not-fixed').delay(1000).animate({
    top: window.innerHeight + window.scrollY - 56 + "px"
}, WantedSpeed, function() {
    // Animation complete.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is throttle your scroll callback:

```
(function() {
  var scrollTimer = 0,
      $notFixed = $('.not-fixed');

  function changeFooterPosition() {   
    $notFixed.css('top', window.innerHeight + window.scrollY - 56 + "px").show(300);
  }

  $(document).bind('scroll', function() {
    $notFixed.hide();
    clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
    setTimeout(changeFooterPosition, 50);
  });
}());
```

Comment: Also wanted to say that some devices take a snapshot of the screen when the user scrolls... so the device is essentially scrolling an image.  This is done for performance reasons... but it results in the footer being visible while scrolling on some devices.  There's no way around this.  The snapshot happens before the scroll handler fires.